# How to get individual counts from same table,based on different keywords

Tags: sql, hive

i have different mobile types in a table. Types like iPhone,android,windows etc. I want to get the individual counts of each type using the same query. I used the below query to get count of one type.

```
   `select type,
    count(1) AS total
    from mobile_types where type = 'iPhone'
    group by type;'
```

I got the required o/p using this for one record.

iPhone 1000

But when i try it for multiple records i am getting an error. I used the following for multiple records.

```
   'select type,
    count(1) AS total
    from mobile_types where type = 'iPhone'
    from mobile_types where type = 'windows'
    group by type;'
```

the error i got was "ParseException line 5:0 missing EOF at 'from' near ''iPhone''"

And is there a way to get the output in below format,with types as column names and the count below as row?

|iPhone|windows|android|

1000    |1500      |900    |

**UPDATE**

I was able to get the individual counts using the below script.

```
'select type,
    count(1) AS total
    from mobile_types where type = 'iPhone' OR type = 'android' OR type = 'windows'
    group by type;'
```

But still need above mentioned o/p format. Current o/p format

iphone 1000

android 900

windows 1500.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the output format you're looking for:

```
select
sum(if(type = 'iphone', 1, 0)) as n_iphone,
sum(if(type = 'android', 1, 0)) as n_android,
sum(if(type = 'windows', 1, 0)) as n_windows
from mobile_types;
```

Comment: It worked. But it is just displaying the output values without the name of the column like                                                          1000 1500 900

Comment: do "set hive.cli.print.header=true;" and then re-run

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the where clause to get the type. This will show a list of all types with the count of each in the total column.

```
select type,
count(*) AS total
from mobile_types 
group by type;
```

**AFTER COMMENT**

```
SELECT type,
COUNT(*) AS total
FROM mobile_types 
WHERE type IN ('IPhone','Android', 'Other Phone Names')
GROUP BY type;
```

Comment: That was my first thought. But the thing is i need only some types in my output.

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect what you'd like to see.

Comment: Thank you that works. Is there a way to display the output like phone type as column name and count of each phone type below the column name?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? (SQL Server, Oracle)

Comment: I suggest opening another question since the answer to this question has been finished. I think that the solution to that is Hive specific and I cannot help further. Sorry :(